# How do I create a user function to return 'FALSE' if a column value string length is less than 5?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I create a user function to return `'FALSE'` if a column value string length is less than 5 and return the original string value if the length is equal to 5?

```py
def z(row):
    if df['column_val'].str.len() < 5:
        return 'FALSE'
    else:
        return df['column_val']
```

I get this error when I try to create a column with this:

```
ValueError: ('The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().', 'occurred at index 0')
```

Comment: `df['column_val'].str.len()` returns a `Series` of boolean values, not a single boolean, causing the problem in your `if` statement.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. How do I make it return a single boolean value instead of a series?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df['new_row'] = df['column_val'].apply(lambda x: 'FALSE' if len(x) < 5 else x)` should give you your answer as a series assigned to `df['new_row']`.

Comment: I suggest you understand lambdas if you don't already; generally very helpful. See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html for some examples.